# How to program numerical integration $\int_t^{\infty}\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}du$?

Tags: matlab, numerical-calculus

I'm facing a problem when program the numerical integration of $\int_t^{\infty}\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}du$, I know that the true value is $\frac{1}{1+t}$, however, when I want to calculate the definite integration numerically, I found the result is very strange like following:

[image]

The blue curve is the true value, the red curve is the numerical integration.

The problem setup is that I know $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ (ranges from $0$ to $1$), then I tried to program following code in matlab:

```
((1./(1+Xi_sort).^2).*(Xi_sort-[0;Xi_sort(1:n-1)]))'*tril(ones(n,n),0)
```

What's wrong with this? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Could you post all the code you use instead of just a piece of it?

Comment: The red one is the integral from $t$ to $1$, not $\infty$

Comment: @Empy2 I see, thank you. But I cannot change the range of $X_1$ to $X_2$, how can I remedy this in code? Will interpolation work?